# VBA ribbon - Styles

Tags: excel, vba, controls, ribbon

I am working with a custom ribbon in Excel (VBA + XML). 
I was wondering if there is a control that would emulate the "Styles" functionality from the Home tab of Excel, that being a 2 rows x 3 columns gallery displayed directly in the ribbon, not by clicking a button.

Can anyone let me know if such a control exists and what is it called?

Thank you

Comment: The control available for this is called a Gallery.

Comment: @jkpieterse the gallery control creates a button which you press and then the gallery shows, at least in the examples I found online, that is different from the "Styles" section, which is a rectangle with 2 rows x 5 columns containing other buttons, with Spin buttons and a "More" button to the side. Is there a setting i should use to get the same result?

Comment: I'm afraid the gallery with a button to click to expand it is all there is.